# Can you specify conditional return value types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have written the following function to help with error handling

```
const capture = <T>(
  callback: () => T
): { result?: T; error?: Error } => {
  try {
    return { result: callback(), error: undefined };
  } catch (err) {
    return { result: undefined, error: err as Error };
  }
};
```

Example usage:

```
const { result, error } = capture<number>(() => foo());
if (error) badPath();

console.log("hooray we got a result", result)
```

However the TypeScript compiler will complain:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2532)
const result: number | undefined
```

I understand why the compiler is complaining (this is expected behaviour for using optional params).

However I was wondering if there existed some TypeScript shenanigans that could support conditional return types.

i.e. is there a way we could specify `capture`'s signature such that when `error` doesn't exist, `result` is inferred to exist? And vice versa?

Comment: I've written an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69845257/6548154). TL;DR try it with a union type

Comment: `error: err as Error` don't do this. You are *asking* for bugs. You can `throw` *any* value in Javascript (like `undefined`), not just errors, and the compiler is trying to warn you that you aren't handling the `catch` block properly.

Comment: @A_A When trying union types the output is still inferred to be `{ result: number | undefined; error: Error | undefined }`. It's tricky here, I'm not sure if we can statically determine what the return type is, it seems like something that has to be determined at runtime (although I very well might be wrong).

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for pointing that out, I'll try avoiding `as` usage.

Comment: @utpamas re: unions if that's what you got then you aren't using the union correctly (I didn't follow the link). Instead of having a wrapper object that has *a* type that has an optional result and an optional error, just return `result | Error` and check for which one got returned. You can use the methods described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233215/3757232)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible because TypeScript doesn't know about runtime.

The closest thing that comes to mind is to allow `T` to be undefined

```
(callback: () => T | undefined)
```

and then filter it along with `error`, making the rest of your code understand that `result` at that point is a `number` and can't be undefined.

[image: result type here in number]

```
const capture = <T>(callback: () => T | undefined): { result?: T; error?: Error } => {
  try {
    return { result: callback(), error: undefined }
  } catch (err) {
    return { result: undefined, error: err as Error }
  }
}

const start = () => {
  const { result, error } = capture<number>(() => foo())
  if (error || !result) {
    // something
    return
  }

  // result // here it will be `number`
  // (cannot be undefined because we checked)

  console.log('hooray we got a result', result)
}
```

Comment: And what happens if `callback` decides to `throw undefined;`?

Comment: @JaredSmith this assumes that not having value on `result` is equivalent to having an error, so in that case `if (error || !result)` would trigger `// something`

Comment: No, I mean it's probably better to point out to the OP that is generally an unsafe cast.

Answer (score 5):

- Define the return value of your `capture` function as `{ result: T; error: undefined; } | { result: undefined; error: Error; }`.
- Do not destructure the return type; check its properties instead. TypeScript is not smart enough yet to link the types of distinct variables in this case.

```
const capture = function<T>(
  callback: () => T
): { result: T; error: undefined; } | { result: undefined; error: Error; } {
  try {
    return { result: callback(), error: undefined };
  } catch (err) {
    return { result: undefined, error: err as Error };
  }
}

const retVal = capture<number>(() => foo());
if (retVal.error)
    badPath();
else
    console.log("hooray we got a result", retVal.result);
```

See this [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2&ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAHKBXATgUxgXhgMxTGCgEtwAeAFQD4AKAWACgY54AbNgI3mAGsAuGLQCUOajEpNhggN4xMEFGyiDKAbhgY0aEGkGEAJhjwkwGAxoC+MAD4w5CpSpiHjp8xq069MAKLbdK3smFig0AE9g5hZ5DFQ0MHtYxWVBBA5uPhEAGk0An1cTMwMYSzUQ0tYoYAALIS9RGQqWTHjEhwwU50L3A1yvXUEvGHgIP3zS8ujLJhnGJiNgNnhMfEJiMkS8EBARQTAUAFtOLSnF5dWCIlJwGG4DAAV4KBq9mAA3EBILJiZQSFgrQAauwcKxkOgMOQDsctHQRGJ8DsRMIpiQ8EJgewAHQDNDCZp3eCPZ6vVFMDBsCAYQn-CAgNgYbFsEAAc1oACIajs0PBIgB3LCskCweDJJwc3JYtjYxzKcmMIA).

For a more robust implementation, we need to take into account the case that the error thrown is not an instance of `Error`. In this case, checking the truthness of the `error` property in the result is not sufficient. We could here, for example, switch to test for the existence of the `error` property itself. To do that, let's change the return type to just `{ result: T; } | { error: unknown; }`. An implementation would then look like:

```
const capture = function<T>(
  callback: () => T
): { result: T; } | { error: unknown; } {
  try {
    return { result: callback() };
  } catch (err) {
    return { error: err };
  }
}

const retVal = capture<number>(() => foo());
if ('error' in retVal)
    badPath();
else
    console.log("hooray we got a result", retVal.result);
```

And the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAHKBXATgUxgXhgMxTGCgEtwAeAFQD4AKAWACgY54AbNgI3mAGsAuGLQCUOajEpNhggN4xMEFGyiDKAbhgBfGAB8YcjGjQg0gwrzAgA7mA3aZTFlDQBPfY5byMqNGH1fFZUEEDm4+ES01D20EKGAACyFDNFEHZk9MHz8DIxNBZMjopk0mJgATDGA2eEx8QmIyPzwQEBFBMBQAW05DKMYKqpqsAiJScBhuMoAFeCh4tpgANxASMr6mUEhYTIA1dhxWZHQMcg7uwzoI7HFm1uFhPpI8IQByZJMXmBI-XfZhDxYkxmcxEfQwbAgGABcHAEBAbAwADo2CAAOa0ABE8RaaHgbisWFRIFg8ACSigGIANF4oHs2IiFOSHkwgA).

Comment: And what happens if `callback` decides to `throw undefined;`?

Comment: That would print 'hooray we got a result undefined' as expected. To get more plausible results, you'd have to change the logic, not just the typings.

Comment: No, I mean it's probably better to point out to the OP that is generally an unsafe cast.

Comment: Agreed. I extended my answer, thanks.